# Inconsistent behaviour in arrays created with Array.create and Array.init

Tags: arrays, f#

```
let a = Array.create 3 (Array.create 3 0)
let b = Array.init 3 (fun _ -> Array.init 3 (fun _ -> 0))
```

These two arrays both have the signature int [] [] and initial value [|[|0; 0; 0|]; [|0; 0; 0|]; [|0; 0; 0|]|].

However:

```
a.[0].[0] <- 3
b.[0].[0] <- 3
```

produces different results:

```
a: [|[|3; 0; 0|]; [|3; 0; 0|]; [|3; 0; 0|]|]
b: [|[|3; 0; 0|]; [|0; 0; 0|]; [|0; 0; 0|]|]
```

The result for b is the one I would have expected for both.

It seems logical to me that identical signatures should act in an identical manner. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to Array.create is a singular value, which is used to initialize every slot in the array. I.e., think of the following:

```
let a =
    let v = Array.create 3 0
    Array.create 3 v
```

`v` is stored into all 3 slots of `a`, so modifying any element in `a` affects all 3 slots.

EDIT: Consider also the logically equivelent:

```
let b =
    let v = Array.create 3 0
    Array.init 3 (fun _ -> v)
```

Comment: Of course, yes, that makes perfect sense @ildjarn. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In the first version, (Array.create 3 0) is evaluated BEFORE it is passed as an argument, so all the cells of the array get the same value.
Arrays are reference types, so practically all cells are the same.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems logical to me that identical signatures should act in an identical manner. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

**Sharing**

Using `Array.create` results in an array of elements that share the same value. Using `Array.init` invokes a function to create the value of each element.

Consequently, this allocates two arrays:

```
let a = Array.create 3 (Array.create 3 0)
```

whereas this allocates four arrays:

```
let b = Array.init 3 (fun _ -> Array.init 3 (fun _ -> 0))
```

You may prefer to think of it in terms of array literals where the former is equivalent to:

```
let xs = [|0;0;0|]
[|xs;xs;xs|]
```

and the latter is equivalent to:

```
let xs = [|0;0;0|]
let ys = [|0;0;0|]
let zs = [|0;0;0|]
[|xs;ys;zs|]
```